# Batch script to list selected .xml having date in the name having file names to a .txt file

Tags: xml, batch-file, batch-processing

Thanks in Advance for your kind help.

I have some xml files having date in the file name in a folder.

Example

- Profile-20131126-1.xml
- Profile-20131125-2.xml
- Profile-20131124-5.xml
- Logic145242013_11_26.xml
- Logic154752013_11_25.xml
- Logic154852013_11_24.xml

Now I need to get the file name for the days lesser than 26-11-2013 to a .txt file. The date can be seen in the file names.

So the output should be like below.

- Profile-20131125-2.xml
- Profile-20131124-5.xml
- Logic154752013_11_25.xml
- Logic154852013_11_24.xml

Can some one please help me for the batch script.

Thanks and Regards,
Siva

Comment: Are the examples the **ONLY** file structures in that directory? Do the Logic files always have 5 numbers before the date part?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see other solution here than split the problem in 2 parts: 
for Profile-*.xml files 
and  for Logic *.xml ones.

In script below I used comparison with 20131126 to get the older files. Split file names in parts in order to get the date in format above to be able to compare.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set mydate=20131126

rem take each file name
for %%a in (Profile-*-*.xml) do (
    rem take only data, split by dash and take second value
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%f in ("%%a") do (
        rem compare with 20131126
        if %%f LSS %mydate% (   
            echo %%a>>txtfile.txt
            rem Add processing of your files here  
        )
    )
)

rem take each file name
for %%a in (Logic*_*_*.xml) do (     
    rem put the value in a local parameter
    set filename=%%a
    rem take only the last 14 to 4 letters 
    set filename=!filename:~-14,-4!
    rem remove underscores
    set filename=!filename:_=!
    rem compare with 20131126
    if !filename! LSS %mydate% (         
        echo %%a>>txtfile.txt
        rem Add processing of your files here 
    )   
)
```

Comment: Hi Mihai, The problem I face is date corresponds to current date. for example Think today date is 28-11-2013. and In the folder I have files  Profile-20131126-1.xml
Profile-20131125-2.xml
Profile-20131124-5.xml                                             Profile-20131127-5.xml
Logic145242013_11_27.xml
Logic154752013_11_25.xml.   In this case only below files should be entered to .txt file. 
Profile-20131126-1.xml
Profile-20131125-2.xml
Profile-20131124-5.xml                                             
Logic154752013_11_25.xml. I mean to say date part less than current day should be the output

Comment: Hi Siva. Please remove comments from code or put in other lines like I edited. In the original question, you require files with date lesser than 26-11-2013 to be in the output. You can pass current date to script as parameter or get it automatically but this can be tricky.